# SelectedIndex property of a drop down list

Tags: asp.net

In my web application I'm having a drop down list and a text box. I want to disable the text box for certain values in drop down list. I wrote the code for the selectedIndexChanged event of the drop down list. I made the AutoPostBack property of the drop down list true.

But when I'm running the application and selecting a value from the drop down it suddenly change to the initial value. Therefore all the time I get the value 0 for the SelectedIndex. What can I do for this?

Comment: code by example needed..

Answer (score 0):

If you initial dropdown list in onPageLoad event you must to check if it is postback and if so do not initial it again.

```
protected void OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
      // init dropdownlist here
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you make this a rule for yourself: every time you dynamically create or otherwise initialize (e.g. populate, set its properties) a server control, do your best to do that within OnInit event, and do it ALWAYS (regardless of the postback state). The purpose of OnLoad event is to provide a coder a way to manipulate controls that have already been loaded, where that loading should happen within OnInit - simply stated.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing with postbacks to achieve that is an overkill and slow. You should use client-script (javascript) to disable the textbox when certain options are selected in that dropdown. Depending on whether you're using plain js or jquery or something else, that implementation will vary.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable text box client side very easily so why you add AutoPostBack property to the drop down list.

If you want to do something else by adding this property then provide some more details so that we can give you best answer as per you requirment.

To make it disable client-side you can follow the code given below:

**HTML:**

```
<select name="ddlSample" id="ddlSample">
    <option value="1">Enable text box</option>
    <option value="2">Disable text box</option>
</select>
<br />
<input name="txtCode" type="text" id="txtCode" />
```

**JQuery:**

```
$("#ddlSample").change(function(){
    if($(this[this.selectedIndex]).val()=="1")
    {
        $("#txtCode").attr("disabled",false);
        $("#txtCode").focus();    
    }    
    else
    {
        $("#txtCode").attr("disabled",true);
    }    
});
```